# Outgoing VPN PPTP: How to check if TCP port 1723 and GRE protocol port 47 are blocked or not in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, port, tcpip

I am trying to connect to a VPN Server ([BestUKVPN](http://www.bestukvpn.com/)) but I'm failing each time I try.

I get a "691 error" but the username and password are OK.

I searched and I am told that "port 1723" or 'GRE protocol port 47" being blocked can cause this issue as well.

How can I check them and, in case they are blocked, unblock them?

Comment: This might help- `netstat` in cmd gives the status of ports.
Have a look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308127.

Comment: You ISP may not be allowing them, call and ask them if they are. :)

Comment: @techie007:I can easily connect from a Windows Xp machine,If it were the ISP, i shouldn't have been able to connect using windows xp!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
netstat | find "1723"
```

Thats all u need.

Oh and to unblock them, this page may help

http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/help/computer_configuration/configuring_windows_xp_firewall.html

Comment: That command didnt find anything!

Comment: That just means 1723 isn't currently in use. That's all. If you try `netstat` only, that will give you a list of all the currently used ports. The piping to find 1723 wont give you any result if your port isn't even used.

Comment: A couple things to point out. 
**1723  TCP Microsoft Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)**
This works in conjunction with your GRE port 47. It should be active no matter what.
Also try the following:
1) Make sure the Include Windows logon domain check box is unchecked in the Options tab of the dial-up connection's Properties dialog box. 
2) Make sure the dial-up connection's security option is correctly configured to use the Require secured password setting. 
3) Delete all of the *.pwl files and reboot if you are using win9x. 
4) Try another logon ID.

Comment: Well i tried running the vpn connection, and checking the netstat results,thats why i said nothing showed up.When a VPN connection is dialing, it should use that port right?when it fails then it means that port is blocked right?

Comment: When the connection is dialing, the PORT HAS TO BE USED. Correct. It's not necessarily blocked but can also be disabled.(as in the service was disabled) Check the running services and see if PPTP is actually running.

Answer (score 19):

GRE is a protocol, not a port. (A lot of people say "My router isn't blocking any ports" but that's irrelevant.) Your router needs to understand how that protocol works. In particular, assuming that you're using NAT (Network Address Translation), the router will need to replace your private IP address with its public IP address in the outbound packets, then do the reverse on the inbound packets. If your router doesn't understand GRE then you either need to upgrade the firmware or replace the hardware - you'll need to check the manufacturer's documentation.

You could also try a different type of VPN connection. PPTP uses GRE, but L2TP/IPSec and SSTP don't. However, the VPN server will need to support them, and it will need a digital certificate; you will also need a certificate on your computer for L2TP/IPSec. It looks as if "BestUKVPN" only support PPTP, so you'll need to decide whether it's more work to change your router or your server.

Answer (score 14):

From command line, to **check Windows Firewall rules** for 1723 port:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "1723"
```

If you have **no results**, there are no references to any 1723 port (supposedly not blocking).

**If yes**, try to search **more details** about the involved rule. For example:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all > AllPorts.txt
```

Then edit `AllPorts.txt` file and search for `1723` to obtain more info.

To check **GRE protocol**, try:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "gre" /i
```

and repeat the procedure.

Of course, you are always supposed to be able to perform this search at **Windows Firewall screen**, on Windows Control Panel.

> **NOTE:** I assume you are talking about checking outgoing 1723 TCP port
>   and outgoing GRE protocol. Incoming firewalling rules are only needed
>   if you have some VPN server running inside your computer.